# asp.net 'If' operator requires either two or three operands

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I have wrote some code to find out of 3 variables witch is the lowest then display it but i am getting "'If' operator requires either two or three operands." and i am unsure as to what the issue is any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%      

            dim HP_RegularPayment As Integer = HP_RegularPayment
            dim LPC_RegularPayment As Integer = LPC_RegularPayment
            dim PCP_RegularPayment As Integer = PCP_RegularPayment

            if HP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment and if HP_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
                %>
                <div id="detailsprice" style="height:70px; padding-top:5px;"> 
                £<% if DiscountPrice.Text = "" then
                    Response.Write(DiscountPrice.Text) 
                else 
                    Response.Write(Price.Text)
                end if 
                %><br /> <span style="font-size:12px;">Or £<%Response.Write(HP_RegularPayment) %> Per Month With HP Finance</span> </div> <%

            else if LPC_RegularPayment < HP_RegularPayment and if LPC_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
                %>
                <div id="detailsprice" style="height:70px; padding-top:5px;"> 
                £<% if DiscountPrice.Text = "" then
                    Response.Write(DiscountPrice.Text) 
                else 
                    Response.Write(Price.Text)
                end if 
                %><br /> <span style="font-size:12px;">Or £<%Response.Write(LPC_RegularPayment) %> 
                Per Month With LP Finance</span> </div> <%

            else if PCP_RegularPayment < HP_RegularPayment and if PCP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment then
                %>
                <div id="detailsprice" style="height:70px; padding-top:5px;"> 
                £<% if DiscountPrice.Text = "" then
                    Response.Write(DiscountPrice.Text) 
                else 
                    Response.Write(Price.Text)
                end if 
                %><br /> <span style="font-size:12px;">Or £<%Response.Write(PCP_RegularPayment) %> Per Month With PCP Finance</span> </div> <%
            else%>

            <div id="detailsprice"> 
                £<% if DiscountPrice.Text = "" then
                    Response.Write(DiscountPrice.Text) 
                else 
                    Response.Write(Price.Text)
                end if 

            end if%>
```

Thanks Lewis

Comment: You need to separate your code from your markup.

Comment: Your right i should but i dont have time to make the code preity this is just a quck and dirty build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've got another `if` within each of the existing `if` statement...

```
if HP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment and **if** HP_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
```

[VB.NET has an operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985) called `If` that takes two or three parameters, and if the first is `Nothing`, it return the second parameter.

Remove it, which makes the line...

```
if HP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment and HP_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
```

I would also agree with @IrishChieftain in his comment, that you should really separate your code and mark-up.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
if HP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment and if HP_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
```

use

```
if HP_RegularPayment < LPC_RegularPayment and HP_RegularPayment < PCP_RegularPayment then
```